# rel attr with jquery always take the first value

Tags: jquery, attr, rel

I have this:

HTML:

```
<div id="selectedsongs">
<a href="#" rel="1">song1></a>
<a href="#" rel="2">song2></a>
<a href="#" rel="3">song3></a>
</div>
```

Then:

```
selectedBtn = $('#selectedsong');

selectedBtn.click(function()
{
  self.selectedsong($('a', this).attr('rel'));
  return false;
});
```

But always takes the rel value of the first link, in this case, the value "1".

Why? :(

Thank you very much! ;-)

Comment: RTFD. http://api.jquery.com/attr/ "The `.attr()` method gets the attribute value for only the _first_ element in the matched set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead :

```
<div id="selectedsongs">
<a href="#" rel="1">song1></a>
<a href="#" rel="2">song2></a>
<a href="#" rel="3">song3></a>
</div>

$('#selectedsongs a').click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/XrWk6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectedsongs a').click(function() {
   selectedsong($(this).attr('rel'));
   return false;
});
```